# subset without using brute-force

Tags: ios, logic, subset, brute-force

I'm trying to find a generic solution to the next problem without using brute force because is for an iOS app.

Let's say I have 3 arrays of elements.

```
arr_a = [1,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,2];
arr_b = [2,2,2,2,3,2,2];
arr_c = [3,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,2,2,3];
```

These arrays will only contain elements 1, 2 or 3. As you noticed, they might have all type of elements or just some of them.

Assuming there's a solution, how would you **randomly** pick X, Y and Z values from the arrays, being X the amount of 1s, Y the amount of 2s and Z the amount of 3s?

Comment: If by "brute force" you mean "count every element", then no, it's not possible.

Comment: Create an `NSCountedSet` from the array.